# Version control system with clients config file, component designs, test documents, issue tracking, PM management

Tags: version-control, windows-server

I currently work at a software firm that makes software that

- has a base that's always the same and
- a single config file that contains all the custom code for the individual clients

We break these extensions up into parts and each part has a script that "imports" these changes into the single config file. We also have a interface that is programed in a more traditional way in C# files and these are kept in a directory.
Update: This needs to have component designs, test documents, issue tracking, PM management, assign and manage individual components to individual developers. Have the ability to quickly look at our C# files and have different versions of those and our config files. We use Share Point for that right now.

We also have two complete versions of the solutions (we test our code and then send it to the client and they test it on their system).

I have been given the task to find a better way to maintain these changes with a version control or revision control system. Given these requirements, I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions of a solution that includes some sort of web interface like GitHub or Atlassian bitbucket or VS Team Services. We are 100% Windows Server (this is a server-based software).

Answer (score 1):

From the description plus your comments you are looking for server software to allow you to manage software projects as well as to provide source control. There are a number of solutions available but I would suggest taking a look at the following *ordered by maturity*:

- [G-Forge Advacnced Server](https://gforgegroup.com/)

  - very mature
  - Any build/development tools that you choose
  - essentially the same interface that you get at [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/)
  - CentOS or RedHat Enterprise Linux but can be run from a VM
  - can be tailored for your company
  - free installation for up to 15 users & unlimited projects
  - Corporate pricing starts at $17.50 per month per atcive user
  - Discounts for large firms, non-profits & education
  - Free Plug-ins to work with Jenkins, Visual Studio, Eclipse, MS Project
  - Supports SVN, git, Perforce, CSV & Visual Sorce Safe
  - Tickets, Blogs, Wikis, e-mail, File Release System & Management tools
  - Most management is browser based
- [gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/)

  - Based on git for source code version control
  - Any development tool chain
  - Online hosted or local install
  - Ubuntu, Debian, CentOS or VM
  - Custom look and feel
  - Comunity Edition is Free, Gratis & Open Source
  - code reviews, issue tracking, activity feeds and wikis
  - Issue Management, Code Snippets & Web Hooks
  - CI Integration with Jenkins
  - Scalable: support 25,000 users on one server or a highly available active/active cluster
  - Community Support or purchase support package
  - 30 free trial of Enterprise Edition
  - Adds a lot of user management tools, validation, etc.
  - Added priority support
  - $39 per user per year
- [HG Lab](https://hglabhq.com/)

  - Mercurial Based & built for windows
  - Windows server 2008 or later for servers
  - Any development tool chain
  - Code Reviews, Merge Requests
  - Wiki, Web Hooks, Issue Tracking, Private Repositories all on the roadmap
  - Version Control via Mercurial (hg)
  - 45 day evaluation
  - 1 off purchase, perpetual licence for the version you purchase + 1 year of upgrades *licence extensions need to be purchased for future upgrades*
  - Current pricing: 3 users $49, 10 users $349, 30 users $849, unlimited users $2349.

### Comparison Resources:

The following Wikipedia comparison pages provided useful comparisons:

- [Issue Tracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_issue-tracking_systems)
- [Project Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_project_management_software)
- [Version Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_version_control_software)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the kind of thing I am looking for. Thanks. Have you heard of Team Services before? I was looking at that one too

Comment: @Walt I have not used Team Services but worry that it might suffer from the usual MS problems long term - e.g. Upgrade or be damned, our way or no way, we've switched so you must switch, etc. maybe I am getting cynical in my old age!